# Jumbotron size of background image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a Jumbotron background the size of an image.  When I try to do:

```
.jumbotron {
  background: url("img/img.gif");
}
```

The image is cropped within the bounds of the jumbotron; how do I get it so the image is the width of the jumbotron but the length of the image?

Thanks

Comment: Could you link to a JSFiddle with more of your code, please? Without seeing anything else, the best I can do is say to try something like 100% width.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the width and height you would like in the CSS bro.

```
.jumbotron {
  width: x
  background: url("img/img.gif");
}
```

Then have an image class,

```
.img-height {
height: x;
}
```

If you want to get crazy with it and make it dynamically set the jumbotron's width and height I would suggest JQuery.